# How can I make the video player visible?

Tags: html, css

1st the user selects a file, then this file is used as the source of a video player. But the video player is invisible.

I tried messing with properties but nothing worked. My goal is to have the bottom and left bar with a fixed size, and have the video cover the remaining space (as the video should be 16/9, the bars should be of such a size that makes this possible). But the concern here is to make the video player visible.

[image]

```css
.videoPlayerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.leftBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
}

.bottomBar {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 1;
}

.videoPlayerWrapper {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#videoPlayer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoPlayerContainer">
  <div class="leftBar"></div>

  <div class="videoPlayerWrapper">
    <video id="videoPlayer" controls muted></video>
  </div>

  <div class="bottomBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="videoPlayerContainer">
   <div class="main">
    <div class="leftBar"></div>
    <div class="videoPlayerWrapper">
      <video id="videoPlayer" controls muted></video>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottomBar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.leftBar {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: green;
}

.bottomBar {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.videoPlayerWrapper {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56%;
}

#videoPlayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: nothing changed really ): did it work on your machine?

Comment: @Augusto, The Player is visible. You can check it here. Let me know if you still need help!  https://codepen.io/shaheer-dev1/pen/Babpoym

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).